# putārēs āb eadem aniculā esse dēductum

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

The title is from the Satyricon.  As far as I know 'putares' is second person.  This sentences was translated in the Loeb edition as:

It looked as
though the same old lady had brought him there.

The Schmelling commentary just says that it is an infinitive without accusative subject.  Is P using the second person here because it would be analogous to the use of the second person in English with such sentences as:

I was running along and you would have thought I had almost died when I saw x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's basically right. It's an imperfect subjunctive with a present counterfactual meaning: "you would think he had been brought by the same old woman". (As the commentary says, the implied accusative subject *te* is omitted.) This use of *putares* is common in Latin: you can find many relevant examples [with a PHI search](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=putares).